# Tool to generate android app activity flow from source code

Tags: android, android-activity, legacy-code

I'm new in Android application project. It's quite complicated application with lots of activities. First thing that I'd like to know is activity flow. I think that proper way of building any application is to create activity flow BEFORE starting implementation. This is not the case. There's no such thing. I must digg thru the code and checking who started what. It's painful.

Is there any tool which generate activity flow from source code? If not, is parsing all source code and looking for lines like such:

```
nextIntent = new Intent(mContext,LoginActivity.class);
```

and generating a graph or something a good way?

Comment: It may be harder than you think. Not only that you have to find all Activities which would be quite easy. You also have to consider Fragments. A lot of apps just use 2 or 3 Activities and switch Fragments inside the Activity.

Comment: It may be another step - so far my application indeed uses fragments but also a lot of activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can make flow or could generate class diagram using ObjectAid that you can find on Eclips market place